# Field injection in unit tests with Dagger 2

Tags: android, unit-testing, dagger-2

As advised in [Dagger documentation](https://google.github.io/dagger/testing.html), for unit testing we don't have to involve Dagger at all, and for the provided example it makes sense:

```
class ThingDoer {
  private final ThingGetter getter;
  private final ThingPutter putter;

  @Inject ThingDoer(ThingGetter getter, ThingPutter putter) {
    this.getter = getter;
    this.putter = putter;
  }

  String doTheThing(int howManyTimes) { /* … */ }
}
```

With this class structure it is simple to unit test, just mock the `getter` and `putter`, pass them as constructor arguments, instruct mockito what to return when interacting with any of these objects, and then make assertions on `doTheThing(...)`.

Where I am struggling at testing is when I have to unit test a class with a structure similar to this:

```
class ThingDoer {
    @Inject
    ThingGetter getter;

    @Inject
    ThingPutter putter;

    @Inject
    ThingMaker maker;

    @Inject
    // other 10 objects

    public ThingDoer() {
        App.getThingComponent().inject(this);
    }

    String doTheThing(int howManyTimes) { /* … */ }
}
```

As you can see, I am no longer using constructor injection, but field injection instead. The main reason is not have too many parameters in the constructor.

Is there a way to inject mock dependencies in `ThingDoer` when all its dependencies are provided using field injections?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out a good way of doing this. One possible approach would be this: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/dagger-2-espresso-2-mockito.html. I find it not flexible enough due to the fact that it is a single configuration for all tests. BTW, what you are trying to do is against good OO design - too many dependencies usually mean violation of Single Responsibility Principle. Don't try to "hide" this using Dagger. This is exactly the kind of DI framework abuse that I discussed in this post: http://www.techyourchance.com/dependency-injection-android/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Very good article on DI best practices! In the end I changed the implementation from field to constructor injection. Still, I am interested to find a proper way of unit testing classes using field injection.

Comment: Let me know if you do. You might want to watch this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41139972/android-get-reference-to-started-service-in-instrumentation-test) - I asked a different question, but for the same reason, and, since there weren't any answers except for what I posted in the comment above, I'll be experimenting and post back if I find anything.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but aren't all those field package-accessible? Hence if the tests are in the same package (which they usually are) you can simply do ``thingDoer.getter = ...`` and so on, no? The only problem is that the constructor will try to inject the created object... not sure if you should do this in the constructor

Comment: Hey @Fred, you have a good point. I will give it a try.

Comment: As far as I know, field injection is generally discouraged because of the issues it creates with testing. But unfortunately, with activities it may be required. One approach is as @Fred suggested, replace the injected field with a mock directly. That doesn't always work though, e.g. if you want to replace an injected field which is used in `onCreate`, it is used before you can replace it.
What you can do in that case is create a test application uses a test component and test modules. The test module provides a mock, and you can add a getter on the test component for a reference to the mock.

Answer (score 1):

For field injection, you can create a component and a module which are used in unit test.

Suppose you have the unit test class `ThingDoerTest`, you can make the component injects dependencies to `ThingDoerTest` instead `ThingDoer` and the module provides the mock object instead real object.

In my project, `HomeActivity` has a field injection `HomePresenter`. Following code are some snippets. Hope the code can give you some idea.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class HomeActivityTest implements ActivityLifecycleInjector<HomeActivity>{

    @Rule
    public InjectorActivityTestRule<HomeActivity> activityTestRule = new InjectorActivityTestRule<>(HomeActivity.class, this);

    @Inject
    public HomePresenter mockHomePresenter;

    @Override
    public void beforeOnCreate(HomeActivity homeActivity) {
        Instrumentation instrumentation = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation();
        MyApplication myApplication = (MyApplication) instrumentation.getTargetContext().getApplicationContext();

        TestHomeComponent testHomeComponent = DaggerHomeActivityTest_TestHomeComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(myApplication.getAppComponent())
            .mockHomeModule(new MockHomeModule())
            .build();
        testHomeComponent.inject(HomeActivityTest.this);
        homeActivity.setHomeComponent(testHomeComponent);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOnCreate() throws Exception {
        verify(mockHomePresenter).start();
    }

    @ActivityScope
    @Component(
        dependencies = {
            AppComponent.class
        },
        modules = {
            MockHomeModule.class
        }
    )
    public interface TestHomeComponent extends HomeComponent {
        void inject(HomeActivityTest homeActivityTest);
    }

    @Module
    public class MockHomeModule {
        @ActivityScope
        @Provides
        public HomePresenter provideHomePresenter() {
            return mock(HomePresenter.class);
        }
    }

}
```